# Auto reload the google slide (in full screen presentation mode) when the content updated

Tags: google-chrome, slideshow

I have a big TV connect to my PC via HDMI, which shows the menu in google slide in full screen mode.

The google slide will update periodically, for now every time it updated by my colleague, I have to manually go to the PC and refresh the page.

Is there's a way to make it auto refresh the content whenever my colleague update the google slide?